# Python can you reload `from x import y` from another module z?

Tags: python

I am working on some legacy code and I will need to refresh some imported variable for another module. Eg.

module a:

```
# load from database
MAPPINGS = {...}
```

module b:

```
import a

def dowork():
    for key,value in a.MAPPINGS.iteritems():
        print key
```

module c:

```
# admin section
def manage_mapping():
    ....
    # refresh a.MAPPINGS
```

Lets assume a.MAPPINGS gets imported in other modules `e, f, g` etc, is it possible to reload module a.MAPPINGS and all other modules gets a new `a.MAPPINGS`?

Ref: I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015405/reloading-module-which-has-been-imported-to-another-module) but it's more like refreshing in module b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If things are structured exactly the way you've written your example in the question body (but not in your title), then for me in Python 2.7  a simple `reload(a)` in `c.py` works as you want:

```
# a.by
import time
MAPPINGS = {time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'):''}


# b.py
import a
def dowork():
    for key,value in a.MAPPINGS.iteritems():
        print key


# c.py
import a
def manage_mapping():
    reload(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    from b import dowork
    dowork()
    time.sleep(2)
    manage_mapping()
    dowork()
```

If I do

```
$ python c.py
```

then I get:

```
2017-05-24 16:31:31
2017-05-24 16:31:33
```

which indicates `c` has successfully refreshed `a.MAPPINGS` from `b`'s point of view.

Now, if `b.py` contained `from a import MAPPINGS` (as in your *title*) followed by a reference to `MAPPINGS`,  instead of `import a` followed by a reference to `a.MAPPINGS`,  then that's different:

```
# b.py
from a import MAPPINGS
def dowork():
    for key,value in MAPPINGS.iteritems():
        print key
```

In this case, `b.py` creates its own association between the name `'MAPPINGS'` and the **original** `dict` created in module `a`.  If `a.py` is re-run, it creates a new `dict` but module `b` still contains, and uses, its own reference to the old one. So now you'll get two timestamps the same.   There are two potential fixes:  (1) change to `import a` + `a.MAPPINGS` as above, instead of `from a import MAPPINGS` + `MAPPINGS`,  or (2) move the import down into `dowork()` so the refreshed `MAPPINGS` is re-imported locally every time you want to use it:

```
# b.py
def dowork():
    from a import MAPPINGS
    for key,value in MAPPINGS.iteritems():
        print key
```

I would go with approach (1).

Comment: Actually that's not true.  I would go with approach (1) ***if*** you forced me to use `reload` as part of the solution, but on general principles of maintainability/comprehensibility  I would avoid doing that in the first place.  Instead I would make the process of refreshing-and-returning-`MAPPINGS` a function in module `a`.